# NSURL is not find When URL string with space parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have use UserName=raj and pwd=space but that url string not use in NSURL.

```
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.com/data/image/sd.php?Uname=raj&password=Space"];

NSURL *Url =  [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.com/data/image/sd.php?Uname=raj&password=Space"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:
[urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/data/image/sd.php?Uname=raj&password=Space"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting values from textfield then,Try this:

```
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.com/data/image/sd.php?Uname=%@&password=%@",[usernameField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding],[passwordField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```